# Overridden method from interface not found when calling

Tags: java, interface, overriding

I'm trying to call a divide method that's overridden from an interface class. All similar methods (add, subtract, multiply) work just fine, except divide for some reason isn't found. Here's what I have below:

Arithmetic Interface class

```
public interface Arithmetic {

    public Object add(Object obj);

    public Object subtract(Object obj);

    public Object multiply(Object obj);

    public Object divide(Object obj);
}
```

Number class (Arithmetic methods are overridden below, divide being the last one)

```
public class Number implements Comparable,Arithmetic{
    /**
     * A string representing a non-negative number
     */
    private String value;
    /**
     * An integer greater than or equals to 2.
     */
    private int base;

    /**
     * - for negative numbers and otherwise null
     */
    private char sign;

    /**
     * creates 0 base 2.
     */
    public Number()
    {
        value = "0";
        base = 2;
    }

    /**
     * creates a number in a specified based using the specified parameters.
     * @param num a string representing a non-negative number with digit
     * written in uppercase letters.
     * @param radix the base of the number
     */
    public Number(String num, int radix) throws InvalidNumberException
    {
        String list = ".-0123456ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        Boolean pars = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            if (num.indexOf(list.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                pars = true;
            }
        }
        if (radix < 1 || radix > 35) {
            throw new InvalidNumberException("Number invoked with a radix less than 1 or greater than 35.");
        } else if ((num.indexOf(".") != num.lastIndexOf(".")) || (num.indexOf("-") != num.lastIndexOf("-"))) {
            throw new InvalidNumberException("Number invoked with more than one dash or period in string.");
        } else if (num.indexOf("-") != 0) {
            throw new InvalidNumberException("Number invoked with dash not at beginning of string.");
        } else if (num.indexOf(".") == num.length()) {
            throw new InvalidNumberException("Number invoked with period at end of string.");
        }
        else if (pars == true) {
            throw new InvalidNumberException("Number invoked with invalid character.");
        }
        Boolean test=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            if ((num.charAt(i) != '-') || (num.charAt(i) != '.')) {
                if (toValue(num.charAt(i)) >= radix) {
                    test=true;
                    throw new InvalidNumberException("Number invoked with digit greater or equal to radix.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(test==false){
            value = num;
            base = radix;
        } 
    }    

    /**
     * Converts a digit to its integer equivalent
     * @param digit 0...9 or A...Z to be converted
     * @return the integer equivalent of the specified digit.
     */  
    private int toValue(char digit)
    {
        return Character.getNumericValue(digit);
    }

    /**
     * Converts this integer to its equivalent digit
     * @param anInt an integer between 0-35
     * @return the digit equivalent to an integer
     */
    private char toDigit(int anInt)
    {        
        if(anInt >= 0 && anInt <= 9)
            return (char)(anInt + 48);

        else if(anInt >= 10 && anInt <= 35)
            return (char)(anInt + 55);

        else
            return (char)(-1);
    }

    /**
     * converts a number to its decimal equivalent (double).
     * @return the decimal equivalent of a number
     */
    private double toDouble()
    {
        if (base == 10)
            return Double.parseDouble(value);
        int periodIndex = value.indexOf('.');
        double base10Num = 0;
        int i;
        int radix = base;
        String whole;
        if (periodIndex >=0)
            whole = value.substring(0, periodIndex);
        else
            whole = value;
        int j=0;
        int wholeLength = whole.length();
        for (i=wholeLength-1; i>=0; i--)
            base10Num = base10Num + toValue(whole.charAt(i))*(int)Math.pow(radix,wholeLength-i-1);
        if (periodIndex >= 0)
        {            
            String fract = value.substring(periodIndex+1,value.length());
            int fractLength = fract.length();
            for (i=0; i<fractLength; i++)
            {
                base10Num = base10Num + toValue(fract.charAt(i))*Math.pow(radix,-i-1);
            }
        }      
        if (sign == '-')
            base10Num *= -1;
        return base10Num;
    }

    /**
     * converts a decimal number (double) to its equivalent representation
     * in a given base.
     * @param dec the decimal (base 10) number
     * @radix the base to convert the number to.
     * @return the equivalent number in the specified base
     */    
    private Number doubleToNumber(double dec, int radix)
    {
        if (radix == 10)
            return new Number(Double.toString(dec),radix);
        String numSign="";
        if (dec < 0)
        {
            numSign = "-";
            dec = -dec;
        }
        int whole = (int)dec;
        double fract = dec - whole;
        String numStr = "";
        while (whole != 0)
        {
            numStr = toDigit(whole%radix) + numStr;
            whole = whole / radix;
        }
        if (fract != 0)
        {
            numStr += ".";        
            int tolerance = 20;        
            int precision = 0;        
            while (precision < tolerance && fract != 0)        
            {
               fract = fract * radix;
               numStr += toDigit((int)(fract));
               precision++;
               fract = fract - (int)fract;               
            }
        }
        return new Number(numSign+numStr,radix);
    }

    /**
     * Gives a string representation of this number in the
     * format number[base].
     * @return a string representation of this number
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s%s[%d]", this.sign, this.value, this.base);
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj instanceof Number))
            return false;
        return (this.toDouble()==((Number)obj).toDouble()); 
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (!(obj instanceof Number))throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else if(this.toDouble()<((Number)obj).toDouble()) return -1;
        else if(this.toDouble()>((Number)obj).toDouble()) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

    /**
     * This method adds two numbers from two different objects
     * @param obj the number of the object inputted from user
     * @return a new added number object
     */

    @Override
    public Object add(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!(obj instanceof Number)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (this.base != ((Number) obj).base) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return doubleToNumber((this.toDouble() + ((Number) obj).toDouble()), ((Number) obj).base);
        }
    }

   /**
    * This method subtracts two numbers from two different objects
    * @param obj the number of the object inputted from user
    * @return a new subtracted number object
    */

    @Override
    public Object subtract(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!(obj instanceof Number)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (this.base != ((Number) obj).base) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return doubleToNumber((this.toDouble() - ((Number)obj).toDouble()), ((Number) obj).base);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method multiplies two numbers from two different objects
     * @param obj the number of the object inputted from user
     * @return a new multiplied number object
     */

    @Override
    public Object multiply(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        if (!(obj instanceof Number)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (this.base != ((Number) obj).base) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return doubleToNumber(this.toDouble() * ((Number)obj).toDouble(), ((Number) obj).base);
        }
    }


   /**
    * This method divides two numbers from two different objects
    * @param obj the number of the object inputted from user
    * @return a new divided number object
    */

    @Override
    public Object divide(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!(obj instanceof Number)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (this.base != ((Number) obj).base) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (((Number) obj).toDouble() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return doubleToNumber((this.toDouble() / ((Number) obj).toDouble()), ((Number) obj).base);
        }
    }

}
```

And finally my demo class, NumberDemo

```
public class NumberDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Number a = new Number("12.25", 8);
        Number b = new Number("13.75", 8);

        System.out.println(a.toString() + " + "  + b.toString() + " = " + 
                           a.add(b));

        a = new Number("ABC.75", 16);
        b = new Number("18.5F", 16);
        Number c = new Number("2.FB", 16);

        System.out.println("(" + a.toString() + " - " + b.toString() + ") / " +
                           c.toString() + " = " + (a.subtract(b)).divide(c));

        a = new Number("3.45", 9);
        b = new Number("32.25", 9);
        c = new Number("3.05", 9);

        System.out.println(a.toString() + "(" + b.toString() + " + " +
                           c.toString() + " = " + a.multiply(b.add(c)));

        a = new Number("10111.11", 2);
        b = new Number("1100110.01", 2);
        c = new Number("-101", 2);

        System.out.println("(" + a.toString() + " - " + b.toString() + ") / " +
                           c.toString() + " = " + (a.subtract(b)).divide(c));

        a = new Number("-5", 8);
        b = new Number("5", 8);

        System.out.println(a.toString() + " x " + b.toString() + " = " + 
                           a.multiply(b));

        a = new Number("-0.5", 8);
        b = a;

        System.out.println(a.toString() + " x " + b.toString() + " = " + 
                           a.multiply(b));
    }
}
```

When I call all the arithmetic methods, they appear to be called just fine, however calling divide brings me the error tooltip:

```
cannot find symbol
    symbol: method divide(Number)
    location: class Object
```

I can't seem to find the reason for this, can anyone spot it?

This is my first time using Stockoverflow, so please let me know if anything's apart from the format norm.

Comment: What do you think having a return type of `Object` does?

Comment: Exactly as @SotiriosDelimanolis says, the compiler knows only that your math methods return Object type, and Object has no divide method. Consider using parameterized classes.

Comment: You will have the same problem if you replace division with any other of your methods.

Comment: [tag:JavaScript] tag removed. Your question has nothing to do with this programming language.

Comment: Choosing `Number` as the name of your class is a poor choice - it clashes with `java.lang.Number`

Comment: Sorry, this program is one I'm doing for a programming course, Number is the instructed name of the class that we must use, so there's not much flexibility there.